# How to convert 2d lidar data to 3d point cloud data. the laser range finder i am using is the Hokuyo URG-04LX Scanning Laser Rangefinder

Tags: ros, lidar, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

2d lidar data to 3d point cloud data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221347/i-am-trying-to-convert-2d-lidar-data-to-3d-point-cloud-data.-the-laser-range-finder-i-am-using-is-the--hokuyo-urg-04lx-scanning-laser-rangefinder.-i-am-fairly-new-to-ros-and-i-was-wondering-if-anyone-knows-how-i-can-get-started./) by [mllmjk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25153/mllmjk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-23**:
Please state your problem in the text, not in the title. Also please provide more information like what you are trying to achieve? To have 3D voxel map, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are tools to convert a laser scan into a point cloud in the [laser_geometry packatge](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0